# SVG CSS3 animation coordinates glitch

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I have created an example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/p880j31p/

You can use "OPEN BARRIERS" to open barriers, then you can use "CLOSE BARRIERS" button to close barriers. It all works nicely.

It only changes these classes:

```
.barrierOpen{
    transform: matrix(0.1,0,0,1,-7,0);
}

.barrierClosed{
    transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

But if you open the barriers, and then use "TOGGLE VISIBILITY" button (2 times, once to hide it, once to show it again), the barriers are badly positioned. If you then try to close them, its all fixed again.

Can anyone explain this? I think it's SVG vs CSS coordinates fighting, but is there any nice solution?

Comment: Which browser are you using? I'm using a slightly older version of Chrome and it looks fine.

Comment: Latest chrome on Windows looks fine. Firefox animation out due to know issues with transform. IE11 is buggy (svg too small, close does not work)

Comment: I'm using Chrome (latest, I hope), I have this in my application for about a half a year, so it is not related to any new version. I checked it in Firefox now and I see that there it really works badly. I have an ugly hack that removes the class and adds it again to fix the open barrier positions everytime the svg is hidden and displayed again. On Chrome on android tablet it is the same as on desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in the SVG code. It looks like it is necessary to position elements using groups and transform attributes, then it works on all browsers correctly.

So from code for barrier:

```
<g  id="barrierWrapper-40300"
        transform="translate(21.399381,0)">
   <g>
    <!-- selection -->
    <rect stroke="transparent" x="353" y="354.8" fill="transparent" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" id="barrier-40300" height="41.2" width="75" style="transform-origin: center;" />
   </g>
   <g  id="barrierOpacity-40300">
    <g>
     <!-- diag state -->
     <rect stroke="#92d050" fill="#92d050" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" height="18.883333" width="20.6" id="barrierDiagState-40300" y="366.816667" x="358.15"/>
    </g>
    <g>
     <!-- inner gray part -->
     <rect stroke="#000000"  fill="#737373" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" height="15.45" width="17.166667" y="368.533333" x="359.866667"/>
    </g>
    <g id="barrierPole-40300" style="transform-origin: top left;transition: all 4.5s linear;">
     <!-- actual barrier -->
     <rect stroke="#000000"  fill="#ffffff" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" height="5.15" width="40" y="373.683333" x="377.033333"/>
     <rect  fill="#ff0000" height="5.15" width="13.733333" y="373.683333" x="390.766667"/>
    </g>
    <g>
     <text transform="matrix(0.34333333373069763,0,0,0.34333333373069763,141.8399999141693,298.7833331525326) "  font-size="32px" fill="#000" font-family="Arial" id="barrierLabel-40300" y="191.15534" x="635.029126">A4</text>
     <image  id="barrierErrorIcon-40300" width="4.806667" height="4.806667" y="358.95" x="378.166667"  visibility="hidden" xlink:href="/images/error-bitmap.png"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
```

I created:

```
<g transform="translate(381 368)" id="barrierWrapper-40300">
     <g transform="translate(-10,-11)">
      <!-- selection -->
      <rect stroke="transparent" x="0" y="0" fill="transparent" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" id="barrier-40300" height="40" width="80" style="transform-origin: 6px 23px;" />
     </g>
     <g id="barrierOpacity-40300">
    <g>
     <!-- diag state -->
     <rect stroke="#92d050" fill="#92d050" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" height="19" width="20" id="barrierDiagState-40300" y="0" x="0"/>
    </g>
    <g>
     <!-- inner gray part -->
     <rect stroke="#000000" fill="#737373" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" height="15" width="16" y="2" x="2"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(15,0)">
    <g id="barrierPole-40300" style="transform-origin: top left;transition: all 4.5s linear;">
     <!-- actual barrier -->
       <rect stroke="#000000"  fill="#ffffff" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" height="5" width="40" y="7" x="3"/>
       <rect  fill="#ff0000" height="5" width="13" y="7" x="16"/>
    </g>
    </g>
    <g>
     <text  font-size="12px" fill="#000" font-family="Arial" id="barrierLabel-40300" y="0" x="0" >A4</text>
     <image  id="barrierErrorIcon-40300" width="5" height="5" y="0" x="0" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-6,-7)" visibility="hidden" href="images/error-bitmap.png"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
```

And that works ok. Notice the x and y attributes of rect elements are now just small numbers and all of the major positioing is done via translate and groups.